Usefulness of void pointer in C and C++
I know that void type means no value at all https://www.gnu.org/software/c-intro-and-ref/manual/html_node/The-Void-Type.html in C. But, I have seen some code in C in which some parameter variables were passed as void pointer :
return_type my_function_signature(void* param1, int num_count, double real_value){
      type_to_cast_to var_param1 = (type_to_cast_to *)param1;
      // write something here
    enter code here
    return return_value;

}

I wonder, what's the use of having void* param1 in parameter list, when in the body of the function one knows exactly the type to cast ?
It's not like template functions in C++ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template.
Any help from the connoisseurs of C and C++ ?

Really limit your question to either "C" or "C++". In C++  only use void* when, dealing with a legacy "C" api or when you know what templates and type erasure mean.

It's usefulness is to hide implementation details.  The "outside" user of the pointer just knows that it is an opaque pointer, but within the code, it casts it to the right type.

@Eljay the risk of doing that in C++, is that one may try to cast raw data to a class instance which doesn't starts its lifetime and thus is incorrect.

Think of malloc for example. It is returning a pointer to something that does not have any particular type until it is being used to store something.

Also take a look at pthreads for example and how the thread function is being passed into it. When you need a somewhat "generic" API, you need to have a way to have some kind of "universal" type that can be legally converted to other types.

@Eljay This can be achieved with forward declaration of some type. This have advantage to being pointer to correct type and not exposing implementation to "outside" user. void pointers in C used to pass pointers to "any" data. Like in example with malloc or passing opaque user data back to user.

@Pepijn Kramer the question concerns uniqely "C". But it isn't uncommun to see them in "C++" as well.
As you mentioned the legacy functions.

Definitely ask in the C context. If you ask in the C++ context you'll just get a river of "Why shoot yourself in the face?" comments. If you're lucky someone will compose an answer showing how you can avoid void pointers in every instance that does not involve legacy code. Which answers the question as "Not generally useful in C++" .

Some confusion might be coming from the fact that the void type is for "nothing" but the void* is a pointer to "anything"

Used in MPI for parallel processing for distributing a general datatype: e.g. https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.0.x/www3/MPI_Sendrecv.html

@Eljay for simple usage, I just look at the definition of the function and feed it the number of variables with their respective types without having to go look at the source file where it was definied. So, I don't see the risk in it. memcpy, memmove, etc.

The danger is in the function expects a given type and the compiler cannot check that the type of the argument actually does match the expected, making it easy to accidentally pass in a foo rather than a bar and not know until the program fails at runtime. memcpy and memmove are just operating on blobs of memory without applying any interpretation on what they are copying. They can't fail, but the programmer can still use them wrong and see the results of the results of the mistake later.

@EugeneSh. pthreads is a legacy api.

memset, memcpy and memmove  are "C" style API's too. And in general have no place in modern C++ anymore either. You can clear structs at initialization. struct S{ int x; }; S s{}. You can use typesafe std::copy instead of memcpy. Etc... that's what @user4581301 means when he says C++ has ways to avoid void* in every instance.

The answer below uses qsort as an example. Good example, but qsort is another C function. The C++ Standard Library's sorting functions are templated, allowing the compiler to infer the types and make certain that they make sense when building the program. This is generally a better time to fix the problem than when you're in the field with an angry customer.

Also note that the example given above, MPI, is library primarily written in C and exposing a C interface. C++ interfaces tend to not be portable (several reasons for this), so you're either releasing the library as code for the users to build (but use a package manager to do the grunt work where possible) or is distributed as a binary wrapped in a C interface, and here is where you may find yourself using void * in C++.

type_to_cast_to var_param1 = (type_to_cast_to *)param1; is bad code - type mismatch.  type_to_cast_to * is not the same type as type_to_cast_to.  void is not the same as void *.

Program code is uncountable.

Using a void * as a parameter can be useful for callback functions, where the exact type of the parameter isn't necessarily known to the function that takes the callback, but is known to the programmer who instantiates it.
It can also be useful when working on generic data when the exact type isn't known.
A well-known example of both is the qsort function from the standard library which has the following declaration:
   void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));

Here, the base parameter points to the start of an array, while the function pointer compar takes pointers to two objects to compare.  In both cases the qsort function does not know what the array/element type is.
Suppose you wanted to sort an array of int and an array of float.  You would create the following callback functions:
int comp_int(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const int *i1 = p1;
    const int *i2 = p2;

    if (*i1 < *i2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (*i1 > *i2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int comp_float(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const float *f1 = p1;
    const float *f2 = p2;

    if (*f1 < *f2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (*f1 > *f2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

And the qsort function would be called like this:
int a1[5] = { ... };
float a2[10] = { ... };
qsort(a1, 5, sizeof *a1, comp_int);
qsort(a2, 10, sizeof *a2, comp_float);



I wonder, what's the use of having void* param1 in parameter list, when in the body of the function one knows exactly the type to cast ?

There's little, if any use for that.  If the function is expecting a specific pointer type then I can't think of a situation where it is not better for it to declare the parameter as that specific type, instead of as type void *.
Instead, the use of a parameter or return value of type void * is when the function doesn't know the particular type to which the pointer will point, and doesn't depend on that.  In C++, many of those cases are better handled by templating the type or by using a polymorphic type, but those alternatives are not available in C.
